# Angular Unit test for subscribe with EventEmitter

Tags: angular

How to write unit test case for following code?

```
import {EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {CustomService} from '@service/customService';
//
@Output() passVal = new EventEmitter<any>();
constructor(private customService: CustomService){}

ngOnInit(): void{
  this.callBackEvent();
}

callBackEvent(){
  this.customService.getEvent.subscribe((val: boolean) => {
    if(val){
     this.passVal.emit(true)
    }
  })
}
```

How to write unit test case for subscribe with event emitter

Answer (score -1):

Usually we try not to subscribe in tests - should be fine if you do

`const eventEmitterSpy = jest.spyOn(component.passVal, 'emit')`

and then expect it to have been called with the expected value like this:

`expect(eventEmitterSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true)`

Also you need to mock a return value for your service.

`jest.spyOn(this.customService, 'getEvent').mockReturnValue(of(true))`

should do the trick. Of course you have to provide this service in the config of your describe block.

Anyways it might be more convenient to pass `val` directly to the emitter without having this redundant if statement...